Is there a way to bring back the old language switcher in macOS?
In the recent versions of macOS (I don't know when it first started) they introduced a new language switcher.
Previously it was like this, if you press the globe key (unless you changed this in settings) or press ctrl+space:

It would show a box in the middle of the screen which you can cycle your input languages. This menu showed the names of the languages.

Now it is like this in most places:

A small menu is shown below the active text box with only the symbols which represent the language and no text description.

The problem is, this small menu doesn't appear in some apps, if no text box is highlighted.
In most cases, macOS reverts to the old language switcher, but in some apps like Microsoft Excel, it does not show any.
The only indicator that the language is changed is the logo in the menu bar, and that only if you have the icon enabled.
Another thing is, if you have multiple similar looking input languages, for example the different Japanese inputs, I often use the menu bar icon to switch between them because at a glance I can't differentiate them from the tiny icon in the small language switcher itself.
Is there a way to disable the new language switcher using a hack of some sort, so that it always shows the old one? I am admin on this MacBook so it wouldn't be a problem.
